# What should our elevator pitch be?

Tags: discussion

Question 5 of [The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) pretty much says it all:

> What’s the “elevator pitch” for our site? Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one
>   floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The
>   elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is
>   about. Every word counts!
>
> Once decided, it can be sliced and diced to form:
>
> the tagline, the motto, the blurb under the logo, a convenience redirect
>   “nickname” for the site, perhaps eventually the domain name in some
>   form (Due to a variety of practical difficulties with domain names, we
>   prefer to de-emphasize domain name selection. Most sites will retain
>   their topic.stackexchange.com names indefinitely.)
>
> Naming is hard — really hard. But if you can come up with a sensible
>   elevator pitch for your community, it’s a great starting point.

Keep in mind that any random stranger you meet on an elevator may or may not be familiar with other woodworking websites and may even be an avid contributor on said sites, so you may need to differentiate WW.SE from those other sites.

I invited some well-known Internet woodworkers early on and of the couple who responded, the reaction was, "Isn't that just like reddit?"

You have 30 seconds. Ready...go!

Comment: I ran out of time thinking about it....... I might need more than 30 seconds

Comment: It's different from all the other sites in that there is no "look at what I made". Probably not a selling point for many people, but it's a difference!

Comment: The way I've tried selling it thus far is to explain that you don't have to go digging through pages upon pages of posts to find a definitive answer to your questions--the best answers are voted to the top so they're easy to find...but that description alone does make it sound a lot like reddit.

Answer (score 1):

I googled a bunch of Reddit vs. Stack Exchange. Most people criticized the voting culture on SO nowadays and for the most part I don't blame them. To some degree I hope this site will not end up in that strict structure that can seem to punish new users. I have never been a redditer so I my opinion is soley based on my limited experience here and on SO.

I would like to this is the start of something. My only issue is that you could replace woodworking with any site in the SE network. The text might be considered generic but it is what each individual site, and I, strive for.

## First Draft Pitch

This text is my own:

> We are a community of dedicated woodworkers and woodworking enthusiasts. The wide variety of expertise and knowledge will can help anyone expand their views regardless of your current exposure. Sometimes there is not one approach. Instead of a small group of authors we have a constantly growing number bringing fresh ideas and new insight!
>
> This Q&A strives to provide the best content with a proven voting strategy that will show all users which posts the community deems outstanding and notable.

**Disclaimer**

Although my first language I have been known to make silly mistakes with English and writing this in the middle of the night might not have been the best idea. But dammit I've been wanting to step up!

After some reflection and maybe some constructive criticism maybe we can make this better.